# ambiguous partial specialization of const int * with std::enable_if in templated struct

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

When using `std::enable_if` along with a templatized struct it leads to ambiguous partial specialization for `const int*`

In the example below, the compiler complains if the `std::enable_if` is used while there is no issue in compilation when the commented lines are uncommented and `std::enable_if` is not used.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename , typename P = void> struct pType;

template<typename t, typename d, typename config>
struct BP;

template<typename t>
struct MP: std::false_type{};

template<typename t, typename d, typename config>
struct MP<BP<t,d,config>>: std::true_type{};

template <typename T> struct pType <const T *
    ,typename std::enable_if<!MP<T>::value>::type> {};
    // >{};

template <typename T> struct pType <T *  
    ,typename std::enable_if<!MP<T>::value>::type> {};
    // >{};


template <typename T, typename P> struct pType {};

int main() {
    pType<int*> a;
    pType<const int*> b;
}
```

Why does the compiler not understand which version of the struct it has to pick? What would be the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

`const int*` can match `const T*` with T=int, but it also matches `T*` with T=const int.

So matches both versions.

Comment: Why do I not bump into this ambiguity issue if no enable_if statements are used?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `std::enable_if` already you can add another condition via `std::is_const`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename , typename P = void> struct pType;

template<typename t, typename d, typename config>
struct BP;

template<typename t>
struct MP: std::false_type{};

template<typename t, typename d, typename config>
struct MP<BP<t,d,config>>: std::true_type{};

template <typename T> struct pType <T *
    ,typename std::enable_if<!MP<T>::value && std::is_const_v<T>>::type> {
        static const int a = 42;
    };
    // >{};

template <typename T> struct pType <T *  
    ,typename std::enable_if<!MP<T>::value && !std::is_const_v<T>>::type> {
        static const int a = 0;
    };
    // >{};


template <typename T, typename P> struct pType {};

int main() {
    pType<int*> a;
    pType<const int*> b;
    std::cout << a.a;
    std::cout << b.a;
}
```

Comment: Can you please help elaborate why does the original code not work as intended? The compiler finds no ambiguity without the enable_if but with the enable_if why does the ambiguity come up?